# When creating AMI, do additional EBS volumes included in AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I want to create AMI that can reproduce the whole environment inlacing data on additional EBS volumes of an EC2 instance.

My question is, does "additional EBS volumes" (besides the root volume) always included in the AMI snapshots? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "AMI snapshots"? When you create an AMI from an Amazon EC2 instance, you can specify multiple attached volumes. All those volumes will form part of the AMI.

Comment: Thanks John! By AMI snapshot I mean all the snapshot associated with the AMI. From what you said, my understanding is all the EBS volumes are included in the AMI. Thanks!